# php increment letters results in infinite loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop

Im having trouble figuring out if this is a PHP "feature" or bug.

Making a loop like this:

```php
// PHP code
for($i='A1';$i<='c1';$i++){
//something here..
}
```

results in a infinite loop.
Why is this happening?
c1 should be "less" than A1
or at least when A1 reaches C1 they should be equal.

However. what happens is that $i goes all the way to Z1..Z9 and then turs to AA0...etc.

Comment: So maybe my real question is: How does php understand that A1 is less than c1 and therefore execute loop but already at this point knows that c1 is an unreachable "state"

Comment: Does $i++ actually work? I thought increments only happened on integers

Comment: $i++ does work.
it increases A1...A9 then turns to B0...B9.. until Z0..Z9..then goes to AA0..AA9..etc

Comment: Very cool, TIL!

Comment: TIL? What does that mean?

Comment: Today I learned

Comment: What are you intending to do?  Are you wanting incremented uppercase then lowercase strings to be produced?  What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `'c1'` and not `'C1'`, so it won't ever be >=

It sounds like you probably want to do:

```
// PHP code
for($i='A1';$i<=strtoupper('c1');$i++){
//something here..
}
```

Comment: Its not a typo. Its an actual thing that can into my script (user input)

Comment: Then you have to do something else, because incrementing it will result in an infinite loop.  `A1` being incremented will always be uppercase, so will always be less than `c1` as `c` is lowercase.  Incrementing `$i` will never have it "roll over" to lowercase, it will just start appending letters.

Comment: Yes. It appears so. I just thought that in the evaluation of A1<=c1 would me that A1 would eventually reach c1 (lowercase c), but since this never happens i thought it was an error in PHP itself. anyway thx for ur responses

Answer (score 0):

You have a small c in c1, typo?

This works:

```
for($i='A1';$i<='C1';$i++){
    //something here..
    Echo $i ."\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/SHK3E

Comment: Its not a typo. Its an actual thing that can into my script (user input)